# Checking computer is desktop or laptop etc

Tags: vb6, wmi, runtime-error

I am  using following vb6 code to check whether computer is desktop,laptop..etc But the code does not work properly and gives a run time error. I did the same code in VB.net and it works fine.When i did it in vb6 i am getting error.I know that i am missing something which is causing error.can anyone help me to solve the error? Below is the full code in vb6

```
Option Explicit
 Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim oWMI As Object
  Dim oSystem As Object
  Dim SQL As String
  Dim objChassis As Object
  Dim strChassisType As Object
  Dim objWMIService As Object
  Dim colChassis As Object

  Dim strComputer As String
   strComputer = "."
  SQL = "Select * from Win32_SystemEnclosure"


  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colChassis = objWMIService.ExecQuery(SQL)
For Each objChassis In colChassis
        For Each strChassisType In objChassis.ChassisTypes
            Select Case strChassisType
                Case 1
                    MsgBox ("Other")
                Case 2
                    MsgBox ("Unknown")
                Case 3
                    MsgBox ("Desktop")
                Case 4
                    MsgBox ("Low Profile Desktop")
                Case 5
                    MsgBox ("Pizza Box")
                Case 6
                    MsgBox ("Mini Tower")
                Case 7
                    MsgBox ("Tower")
                Case 8
                    MsgBox ("Portable")
                Case 9
                    MsgBox ("Laptop")
                Case 10
                    MsgBox ("Notebook")
                Case 11
                    MsgBox ("Handheld")
                Case 12
                    MsgBox ("Docking Station")
                Case 13
                    MsgBox ("All-in-One")
                Case 14
                    MsgBox ("Sub-Notebook")
                Case 15
                    MsgBox ("Space Saving")
                Case 16
                    MsgBox ("Lunch Box")
                Case 17
                    MsgBox ("Main System Chassis")
                Case 18
                    MsgBox ("Expansion Chassis")
                Case 19
                    MsgBox ("Sub-Chassis")
                Case 20
                    MsgBox ("Bus Expansion Chassis")
                Case 21
                    MsgBox ("Peripheral Chassis")
                Case 22
                    MsgBox ("Storage Chassis")
                Case 23
                    MsgBox ("Rack Mount Chassis")
                Case 24
                    MsgBox ("Sealed-Case PC")
                Case Else
                    MsgBox ("Unknown")
            End Select
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Run-time error 424 object required

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/09/21/how-can-i-determine-if-a-computer-is-a-laptop-or-a-desktop-machine.aspx

Comment: @Arshad I am using the code from the link u hav mentioned itself.Problem is what is the error in my code?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on your function so you can step through it to determine which variable as not been initialized?

Comment: @MarkHall Yes. the error comes for the line " For Each strChassisType In objChassis.ChassisTypes "

Comment: What type is objChassis, you have it declared as an object. A standard object will not have a ChassisType Property. Try casting it to the proper type.

Comment: @MarkHall Ok. But i don't know which type it belongs to. Please help

Comment: Try using the variant data type instead of object.

Comment: @MarkHall I declared objChassis as variant.but it didnt work.Also should i declare ChassisTypes? Also please look at [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394474(v=vs.85).aspx  You may get some idea.

Comment: The problem solved when i declared all objChassis ,strChassisType,objWMIService and colChassis  as Variant

Comment: If you're going to try and use the abominable hungarian notation, and use type prefixes, please make your type prefixes actually match the variable type! `Dim strChassisType As Object`

Answer (score 1):

So you have taken [working VBScript code](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/09/21/how-can-i-determine-if-a-computer-is-a-laptop-or-a-desktop-machine.aspx), and ported it to VB6 by declaring all the variables as `Object`. Now your ported code fails with an error. What could go wrong?

It pays for itself to know about data types used by the languages involved. Luckily, all the variables in VBScript are `Variant`. As per [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> VBScript has only one data type called a Variant. A Variant is a
>   special kind of data type that can contain different kinds of
>   information, depending on how it is used. Because Variant is the only
>   data type in VBScript, it is also the data type returned by all
>   functions in VBScript.
>
> Most of the time, you can just put the kind of data you want in a Variant, and the Variant behaves in a way that is most appropriate for the data it contains.

Even more luckily, VB6 supports the very same `Variant` data type. That is why declaring your variables as `Variant` resolves the problem:

```
  Dim oWMI
  Dim oSystem
  Dim SQL
  Dim objChassis
  Dim strChassisType
  Dim objWMIService
  Dim colChassis
  Dim strComputer
```